# Cloud Foundry node.js application loads slow on iOS Safari mobile

Tags: ios, node.js, mobile-safari, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

We have a Bluemix node.js application that loads perfectly in all browsers, except on Safari Mobile. Even on OSX Safari it works fine. We have tested this with iPhone 5, 6 and different iPads. We have done this over different WiFi networks and 3G/4G.

You can test it here: http://innowall-debug.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/ some of the resources on the first page already load very slowly. This issue is reproducible on the first page.

The strange thing is when you load the site over **[https](https://innowall-debug.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/)** it will load/render fast. What could be the issue causing this to go slow over **[http](http://innowall-debug.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/)** only for Safari mobile?

### **HTTP (slow entry highlighted - check latency 27secs):**

[image]

### HTTPS (fast):

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that you don't see this issue when you run your application locally ?

Comment: yeps, that's how we give demos locally now for iOS Safari. Only when we deploy it.

Comment: unfortunately I can confirm this issue too, have it with liberty runtime. Changing http to https fixed the issue. With websphere liberty it run flawlessly when I run it locally.

Comment: Yeah same thing seemed visible on staticfile-buildpack on Bluemix. although setting custom nginx config with "keepalive_disable msie6 safari;" seemed to help there tho.

Comment: @DrissAmri I am having the same issue, however for me my app is taking over 4 minutes to load only in Mobile Safari on an iPad running iOS 9. The app loads fine on the iPad using chrome. But Safari and WKWebview both fail. I am going to setup my app using https and see if that resolves it as well.

Answer (score 0):

My original instinct was that there is some render-blocking JS/CSS in your application that fails to resolve quickly in Safari. Running your website in Google PageSpeed Insights gives us some good information that could help fix that latency:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Finnowall-debug.eu-gb.mybluemix.net&tab=mobile

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
>   Your page has 4 blocking script resources and 3 blocking CSS
>   resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.

Comment: This does not explain why it works fast on HTTPS and slow on HTTP. So that seems ruled out. Also the latency is up to 20 seconds difference, not a "slight" delay.